# Can't run Python macro in LibreOffice

Tags: python, linux, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I'm trying to learn to write macros for LibreOffice in Python. I made simple macro, put in into `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/` and found it in **Tools/Macros/Organize Macros/Python.../My Macros**. So far all works as expected, macro is visible.

But when I click on it, the **Run** button stays grayed out. I cannot run it. Does anyone know what might be the cause?

Thanks

EDIT: File is executable, I set the rights to 777 just to be sure. Python code is valid.

EDIT2: I reinstalled LibreOffice and it works now. Probably was something wrong with my installation. Script file in `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/` set as executable works. And @ngulam examples worked even before reinstall.

Thanks for all the advice you've given me and have a good day.

Comment: Did you make it executable?

Comment: I've removed the `macros` tag as that's not for software macros like this: _A macro is a rule or pattern that specifies how a certain input sequence (often a sequence of characters) should be mapped to an output sequence (also often a sequence of characters) according to a defined procedure._

Comment: [_A simple Python Macro in LibreOffice 4.0_](https://tmtlakmal.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/a-simple-python-macro-in-libreoffice-4-0/) might help.

Comment: @martineau Yes, I read it and even if I follow instructions there it doesn't work. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macros for OpenOffice/LibreOffice in Python don't have to be executable.

The location is right, though you might want to create a sub-directory (e.g. for CALC or WRITER), and put it in there - since otherwise it will be visible in all other components (where it might not work).

Did you restart LibreOffice after copying?

Comment: The blog post linked to in my comment under this question says the .py file should be placed in `/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/Scripts/python` directory.

Comment: I did restart Office. I think I did everything right but still it's not working.

Comment: @martineau: the location you quoted is for system wide installation of Python scripts (available to all users)

Comment: @lsrom: do the examples work on your system?  
Maybe posting the script could help; in the past I learned that some errors prevent a script name  from showing up at all - they are evaluated at start time for syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Note: For LO 5.2 you need to put your pythons here..

/opt/libreoffice5.2/share/Scripts/python

.. or better still place a link there into a folder where you can edit without sudo ie. issue a command like this..

cd /opt/libreoffice5.2/share/Scripts/python

sudo ln -s /home/rich/Sources/Pythons rje_pythons

where /home/rich/Sources/Pythons is your more convenient folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or similar problem. My script MyCalcHelloWorld.py with the function MyCalcHelloWorld resting in /home/tom/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/ created the library in the Run Macro dialog left pane, but not the script name to run in the right pane.

I have tried to copy one of the preinstalled system-wide python macro scripts from /opt/libreoffice7.5/share/Scripts/python/ to /home/tom/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/ and it showed fine.

In the end I realized, that my script had a syntax error in it (double quotes in a code copied from a web page were not simple double quotes, but UTF-8 characters for upper and lower double quotes) and that was the reason for the script not showing.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to install `sudo apt install libreoffice-script-provider-python`

And the folder of `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/` is correct for your scripts.

Answer (score -1):

If you put your code inside a function named as the file, and returns something or None it should work.
Example: create inside Scripts folder, a file called MakeSomethingPython.py as the following, as you can see i've named the function MakeSomethingPython:

```
#import library or function you need

def MakeSomethingPython( ):
    //code to make something
    //
    return
```